# Retrieving data from a URL using a Java Servlet (Jetty)

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to attach a parameter to a URL on a servlet:

```
<a href="another_servlet?myVariable=<%=thevariable>> Go to this </a>
```

to be retrieved as a variable on another servlet that is called.

which contains the following code :

```
// Database access with a servlet
package ubiserv.simple;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Product extends HttpServlet {
public void service(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException{

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

---

It seems that I can use this code to fetch what I need

```
request.getAttribute
```

but I have searched almost everywhere and I cannot figure out how to put it all together. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, those are query parameters.  Use this to get that value:

```
String myVariable = request.getParameter("myVariable");
```

Check the javadocs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! I was struggling with this for a couple of hours.